# How to sort this list to make the exponent value go first?

Tags: python, list, exponent

Given `list = [10, '3 ^ 2', '2 ^ 3']`, how to sort the list to make the exponents values ( `'3 ^ 2'` and `2 ^ 3` ) are before any `integer` / `float` value and exponent values are sorted from the base.

`Desired Output:` `['2 ^ 3', '3 ^ 2', 10]`

I have tried to `remove()` and `insert()` the value but I can't figure out how to find the index to insert the value in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use list as a variable, it is reserved in python.

Not pretty, but you can use this

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: (-len(str(x).split('^')), str(x).split('^')[0]))
```

This is sorting according to two criteria, first if there is an exponent, and then by the value of the base.

Comment: I don't know how to operate this, could you edit the comment and present how you would do so? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "operate this"? if you substitute "mylist" by your "list" you'll get your desired result

Comment: Note that `list` isn't 'reserved' in Python, only keywords like `def`, 'for'... are. `list` is a builtin function, you *can* use it as a variable name, but the original `list` gets replaced by what you assigned to it and can't be directly accessed anymore in the current scope, which often leads to errors when one tries... so you *shouldn't*.

Comment: Ok, that's what I meant, I should have been more specific